# Differences between properties with pointer and not in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm attending the course of IOS development on itunesU (from Stanford University).
And i got a big doubt about an attribute of a class created in one of this lectures. Let me explain with some code :

I have the class "faceView" whose task is to draw a face, one attribute of that class is "delegate" which is an object that has to implement FaceViewDelegate.

here is the code for interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class FaceView;

@protocol FaceViewDelegate
-(float)smileForFaceView:(FaceView *)requestor;
@end

@interface FaceView : UIView {
    id <FaceViewDelegate> delegate;
    CGFloat scale;
}

@property CGFloat scale;
@property (assign) id <FaceViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

I can't understand why delegate is not a pointer to object, but directly an object. 
Someone could kindly tell me more about this implementation choiche? is this correct ? why ? 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pointer to an object. The type `id` is already a pointer. So when you declare variables of type `id`, they don't need to be pointers. So, these statements are essentially identical (meaning that you can use myIDObj and myObj in exactly the same way):

```
// myIDObj and myObj are both pointers to objects
id myIDObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject* myObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

Comment: May I add it is often the best to use `id` in place of `NSObject*`, some classes may not inherit from NSObject, also `NSObject*` does not anticipate any other messages besides the ones it implements (although it works, compiler will give warnings), where `id` is simply an unknown object which can receive any messages your original object can receive.

Comment: @Adam Ko: I wasn't suggesting that NSObject be used in place of id for random objects, just demonstrating that it's already a pointer and once a variable is declared, they are used the same way.

Answer (score 2):

`delegate` *is* a pointer to an object. The `id` type is defined as:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

So it is already a pointer.